# Let's make difficult-people less difficult

Tags: discussion, tags

This site has a [difficult-people](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difficult-people) tag. However, this is a site about Interpersonal Skills. I would guess that 50% of questions on this site are about someone being "difficult".

Let's remove [difficult-people](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difficult-people) and use more specific tags instead.

Comment: What would you replace this tag with?

Answer (score 5):

Like what more specific tags?

[difficult-people](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difficult-people) *is* useful. Also, I don't think it's being overused - currently there are 8 questions tagged with it, out of 236, which is about 3.39%, nowhere near 50%.

If you have good ideas for more specific tags, I guess that's something to think about, but just a general proposal to kill [difficult-people](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difficult-people) isn't a great idea, in my opinion. I think it's fine the way it is.